# Name is not defined in Django model

Tags: python, django

I have a Django app with the following in its **models.py** file:

```
from django.db import models

class Event(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()
    name = models.TextField(max_length=60)
    venue = models.ForeignKey(Venue)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Venue(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(max_length=60)
    street_address = models.TextField(max_length=60)
    locality = models.TextField(max_length=60)
    region = models.TextField(max_length=60)
    postal_code = models.TextField(max_length=60)
    country_name = models.TextField(max_length=60)
    latitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=6)
    longitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=6)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

But when I run `python manage.py syncdb` I get the following error:

> NameError: name 'Venue' is not defined

Why is this when `class Venue` is in the file? Have I done something wrong? I’ve just been following the Django tutorial at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial01/.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Move the definition of `Venue` before the definition of `Event`.
The reason is that Event references the Venue class in its ForeignKey relationship before Venue is defined.

Or you can do this:

```
venue = models.ForeignKey('Venue')
```