# Django: Ordering by the datetime of many to many model and the datetime of model itself

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models

I want to sort the notes objects by **date_added** *(DateTime)* of **NoteReposter** model (intermediary) first and if it's null then sort it by **date_created** *(DateTime)* of the **Note** model itself.

**This is what I've done so far in my views.py**

```
user = NotepikUser.objects.get(pk=1)

# Combie the notes reposted and notes created of user
notes = Note.objects.filter(Q(notereposter__user=user) | Q(author=user))
notes = notes.order_by("-notereposter__date_added", "-date_created")
```

**And in my models.py**

**Note model**

```
class Note(models.Model):
    note = models.CharField(max_length=2100)
    date_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, blank=True)

    # If the notereposter__date_added is null then sort it using this datetime field
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    author = models.ForeignKey('NotepikUser',
        related_name="%(class)ss_created")

    reposters = models.ManyToManyField('NotepikUser', through="NoteReposter", 
        related_name="%(class)ss_reposted", blank=True)

    categories = models.ManyToManyField('Category', blank=True, 
        related_name='notes')
```

**NoteReposter model (Intermediary)**

```
class NoteReposter(models.Model):
    note = models.ForeignKey("Note", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey("NotepikUser", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, blank=True)

    # Sort by this datetime field first
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

**Unfortunately my solution is not sorting it right**

**Thanks!**

**EDIT**

```
someone created note1 (Note)
note1 date_created is 2016 January 1, 5:00 PM

User2 created note2
note2 date_created is 2016 January 1, 5:30 PM

User2 reposted note1 (note of someone)
notereposter1 (NoteReposter instance) created with user = User2,
             note=note1, date_added = 2016 January 1, 6:00 PM

User2 created note3
note3 date_created is 2016 January 1, 6:30 PM
```

**I want the notes sorted like this**

```
<note3> 6:30 PM,
<notereposter1.note> 6:00pm 
<note2> 5:30pm
```

Comment: unrelated: why do you pass the related models as strings? e.g. `...ManyToManyField('NotepikUser'...` and not `...ManyToManyField(NotepikUser,...` ? Does it work?

Comment: and what is the problem with your solution?

Comment: `I want to sort the notes objects by date_added (DateTime) of NoteReposter model (intermediary)`. Does it make any sense? It's a many2many relation: there are multiple users for each note, i.e. multiple NoteReposter entries for each Note. How do you want to use them for sorting the Notes? e.g. sort the Notes by their latest NoteReposter?

Comment: @Pynchia Yes, it's working. I pass it as a string because NotepikUser model is not defined yet. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18303406/name-is-not-defined-in-django-model]
-Raz It's not sorting it right

Comment: You did not specify related name for Note FK in NoteReposter. It should be `note_reposters`.And you query should be `notes.order_by("-note_reposters__date_added", "-date_created")`.

Comment: I don't have issues with that but do I need to specify related name for note field in NoteReposter model? Why?

Comment: It is One-To-Many relation. There are many reposters for one note as it said Pyncha.

Comment: I have no means to check if it works right now, but you you could annotate the max value of the related set of noteposters and then use that for sorting the notes:
`notes = Note.objects.filter(Q(notereposter__user=user) | Q(author=user));
notes = notes.annotate(latest_reposter=Max(notereposter__date_added)).order_by("-latest_reposter", "-date_created")`

Comment: @Pynchia I already tried annotating earlier but still didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it now. For those interested, here is my solution.

```
from django.db.models import DateTimeField, F, Case, When
notes.annotate(newest_in_vault=Case(When(notereposter__isnull=False,
        then=F("notereposter__date_added")), default=F("date_created"),
        output_field=DateTimeField()))
# Sort it now
notes = notes.order_by("-newest_in_vault")
```